# What's wrong with this TestMethod?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

So I want to learn a little bit of TDD and wanted to see if I could test an Index action which should simply return a View.

The test doesn't pass and the error is

> Test method
>   Summumnet.Tests.Controllers.PhysicalTestsControllerTest.IndexShouldReturnView
>   threw exception:  System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a
>   property access: c => c.FindById(1)

Here's my controller action code:

```
[Authorize]
    [AllowedToEditEHR]
    public class PhysicalTestsController : Controller
    {
        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private IRepository<EHR> ehrRepository;
        private const int PAGESIZE = 5;


        public PhysicalTestsController(IUnitOfWork unit)
        {
            unitOfWork = unit;
            ehrRepository = unitOfWork.EHRs;

        }

        public ActionResult Index(int ehrId, int? page)
        {
            EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);
            var physicaltests = ehr.PhysicalTests.Where(test => !test.IsDeleted).OrderByDescending(test => test.CreationDate);
            List<PhysicalTestListItem> physicalTestsVM = new List<PhysicalTestListItem>();
            Mapper.Map(physicaltests, physicalTestsVM);
            var paginatedTests = physicalTestsVM.ToPagedList(page ?? 0, PAGESIZE);
            return View(paginatedTests);
        }
```

and here's the test

```
[TestClass]
    public class PhysicalTestsControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void IndexShouldReturnView()
        {
            // Arrange

            var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("nacho");
            mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

            var mockUnitofWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            var mockEhrRepository = new Mock<IRepository<EHR>>();
            mockEhrRepository.SetupGet(c => c.FindById(1)).Returns(new EHR { PhysicalTests = new List<PhysicalTest>()});
            mockUnitofWork.SetupGet(p=>p.EHRs).Returns(mockEhrRepository.Object);
            PhysicalTestsController controller = new PhysicalTestsController(mockUnitofWork.Object);
            controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

            // Act
            ViewResult result = controller.Index(1, 0) as ViewResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood you, but why are there so many mocked objects to test a controller? Could you not mock controllercontext especially?

Comment: You are right.. there was no need... I was just copying NerdDinner tests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few pointers:

1. You don't need to mock `HttpContext` for this test. Sure, you have an `Authorize` attribute on your controller, but action filters aren't run when you're unit testing your controllers. So you can just assume that the user will be authenticated and authorized.
2. `SetupGet` is, I believe, pretty obsolete. You should consider using `Setup` instead:

   ```
   mockUnitofWork.Setup(p => p.EHRs).Returns(mockEhrRepository.Object);
   ```

   THis is in fact what is causing your error, since `SetupGet` can only be used on *properties*, while `Setup` can be used on more or less anything. Since `FindById` isn't a property (it's a method), you get that error.
3. When setting up a function call, you usually get better results if you don't give exact input arguments, but rather specify conditions that the input arguments must satisfy. This avoids unexpected and often hard-to-track testing bugs when you pass in two identical - but separate - instances of a class, and expect them to be the same.

   In Moq, you can use the static methods on `It` to do this. If you want to allow for any `int`, just say `It.IsAny<int>()` in place of the integer argument. If you want to be specific, you can use a lambda expression to declare when the behavior should apply, using `It.Is<int>(i => someCondition(i))`. So instead of `.Setup(c => c.FindById(1))` you say

   ```
   mockEhrRepository.Setup(r => r.FindById(It.Is<int>(i => i == 1)).Returns(...)
   ```

   For value types this doesn't make any difference, but I think it's a good habit. I usually choose to not care *which* integer is given, which simplifies the setup expression a little:

   ```
   mockEhrRepository.Setup(r => r.FindById(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(...)
   ```

But to be clear: **The only thing in this post you *need* to do to get rid of your error, is to change `SetupGet` to `Setup`**.

Comment: Yes. The test is passing now.. do you consider this a good approach at writing tests?... Im not sure if I should be mocking The UnitofWork and the Repository instead of writing a FakeRepository class... any recommendations are very appreciated.

Comment: I definitely prefer mocking with Moq over fake classes, for two main reasons: 1) Fake classes can become quite complex, and soon you'll have to write tests for your fakes... 2) If you mock an interface, you can change the expected behavior of that interface in one test, without having to worry about that breaking other tests. With a test class, you'd probably have to write another method, or make an existing one more complicated, and suddenly you're at 1) again... (It is up to you to test the implementation of the IUnitofWork, for example, to make sure your setups align with the real class).

Comment: This solved my problem, but I'm intrigued as to why? If setupGet is obsolete why isn't it flagged as such?